# Python multiprocessing twice process

Tags: python

I try to use 2 processes, but I get an error message saying 'cannot start a process twice'. What is the problem?

I am writing a code that can also run Process2 while Process1 is running.

```
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
import time
import picamera
import picamera.array
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager

Sensor1 = 18
Sensor2 = 23 

# Initialize the GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(Sensor1, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(Sensor2, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


def f1():
    print("funtion 1")
    
def f2():  
    print("funtion 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('start')
 
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Sensor1, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=800)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Sensor2, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=1000)

    process1 = Process(target=f1, args=())
    process2 = Process(target=f2, args=())

    while True:
        if GPIO.event_detected(Sensor1):
            print("camera Sensor detect")
            process1.start()

        elif GPIO.event_detected(Sensor2):
            print("cylinder Sensor detect")
            process2.start()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a full stack trace for the error?

Comment: You are in a `while` loop starting the processes again and again.

Comment: Your `while` loop can call `process1.start()` or `process2.start()` an arbitrary number of times.  That's not how `multiprocessing` works - you need to create a new `Process` each time.

Comment: Can you tell me the solution code??

Comment: solution is already in @jasonharper comment. You have to do `process1 = Process(target=f1, args=())` inside `while True` directly before `process1.start()`. The same with `process2`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is already in @jasonharper comment but it seems you still don't understand it - so I put this code.

You have to create `Process()` inside `while True`

```
while True:
    if GPIO.event_detected(Sensor1):
        print("camera Sensor detect")
        process1 = Process(target=f1, args=())
        process1.start()

    elif GPIO.event_detected(Sensor2):
        print("cylinder Sensor detect")
        process2 = Process(target=f2, args=())
        process2.start()
```